# Programmatically retrieving MultiBindingExpression from control

Tags: wpf, binding

How to retrieve (using code-behind) binding expression from control bounded with using MultiBinding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getmultibindingexpression.aspx) method.

Example:

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="lst" Path="Items.Count" />
                    <Binding ElementName="txtName" Path="Text" />
                    <Binding ElementName="txtAge" Path="Text" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
```

Accesing it from code:

```
TextBlock textblock = FindName("MyTextBlock") as TextBlock;
var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression(textblock, TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

Hope this helps